# Array Post Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

The code I'm working shows all the products and the user assigns the corresponding price to each one through an input. Clicking on a single submit button will update all prices.

The problem is if I put an input for each record the server does not post all the records. Only 500 posts are recorded, not the total. The server does not allow me to modify the `php.ini` file to change the `max_input_vars`. This code works but it shows me the array in a single input. How do I make the form submit via javascript and post the entire array in a single input? What other solution can I use?

This is the code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_categorias4334x)) {
    $precio[] = $row['Precio'];
}
<input type="text" name="precios" value="<?php echo implode(",",$precio);  ?>

//POST

if (isset($_POST['ok'])) {
$precios = $_POST['precios'];
$preciosarr = explode(",", $precios);
print_r($preciosarr); }
```

Before I do that:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_categorias4334x)) {
    $precio = $row['Precio'];
    ?>
    <input type="text" name="precios[]" value="<?php echo $precio; ?>">
    <?php
}
```

But it doesn't post all the records. Only the first 500 records.

Comment: have you tried .htaccess ?

Comment: yes! But doesn't work.

Comment: Using the original solution, have you tried to split and incrementally send 500 values every request?

Comment: Better yet (or worse), why don't you try to send it as a JSON string?

Comment: thanks for the answer. how can i do that?